# How to sum columns in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am a beginner to crystal reports. How do I calculate the sum of a column in crystal report? I want to display like this in crystal report

Expected output: 
       column1
           20
           34

---

sum       54

Comment: Right click on field > Insert > Summary.  Then select the group you want to sum it by.  Not sure if this is what you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Crystal Reports designer view window, right click on the Report Footer , just below the Total field and select Insert -> Summary .

[image]

Then you will get a screen , select the `your column` from the combo box and select Sum from next Combo Box , and summary location Grand Total (Report Footer) . Click Ok button

[image]